# Java extract from nested JSON

Tags: java, json, extract

I want to use financial data from yahoo in my program, it already works. I get the complete JSON content and I can display it. But now I want to **extract** the price as **int**.

```
public class Main {
public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException {


String sURL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/googl/quote?format=json"; //just a string

// Connect to the URL using java's native library
URL url = new URL(sURL);
HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
request.connect();

// Convert to a JSON object to print data
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //convert the input stream to a json element
JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //may be an array, may be an object.

    System.out.print(rootobj);

}
}
```

**EDIT**
This is the JSON data from yahoo

```
{
"list" : { 
"meta" : { 
"type" : "resource-list",
"start" : 0,
"count" : 1
},
"resources" : [ 
{
"resource" : { 
"classname" : "Quote",
"fields" : { 
"name" : "Google Inc.",
"price" : "554.520020",
"symbol" : "GOOGL",
"ts" : "1432324800",
"type" : "equity",
"utctime" : "2015-05-22T20:00:00+0000",
"volume" : "1213288"
}
}
}

]
}
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I changed my code

```
   JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
    JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject obj = root.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject result = obj.get("list").getAsJsonObject();
        String result2 = result.get("resources").toString();


       System.out.print(result2);
```

And now I already get this

```
[{"resource":{"classname":"Quote","fields":{"name":"Google Inc.","price":"554.520020","symbol":"GOOGL","ts":"1432324800","type":"equity","utctime":"2015-05-22T20:00:00+0000","volume":"1213288"}}}]
```

How can I get the "price" now?

**EDIT 3**

Ok I got it now, it works and I only get the price as double, but is this a smart way to solve this task?

```
// Convert to a JSON object to print data
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //convert the input stream to a json element
    JsonObject obj = root.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonObject result = obj.get("list").getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray result2 = result.get("resources").getAsJsonArray();
    JsonObject result3 = result2.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    JsonObject result4 = result3.get("resource").getAsJsonObject();
    JsonObject result5 = result4.get("fields").getAsJsonObject();

    String result6 = result5.get("price").toString();
    result6 = result6.replace("\"", "");
    double value = Double.parseDouble(result6);


   System.out.print(value);
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What exactly do you want to split? Can you provide a clear example?

Comment: I want to split the JSON data to get the price as int value.

Comment: Maybe you mean extract data (not split)?

Comment: Have you think about using a Json parser, such as Gson?

Comment: http://crunchify.com/java-how-to-parse-jsonobject-and-jsonarrays/

Comment: Yes I mean extract data, I want to get the price of the stock from this JSON as an int.

Comment: Please check my EDIT 2.

Comment: First, go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Next, format your JSON so you can read -- indent it at `{` an `[` characters, just as if it were Java code.  Finally, don't try to do everything in one "long chain polymer" statement -- peel the onion, one layer at a time, and log each result or use the debugger to examine it so you know you got what you thought you would get, at each step.

Answer (score 0):

you should reach "fields" object to extract "name", "price" etc.
The `org.json` library is easy to use.  Example code below: your response as a string :

```
    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray arr = obj1.getJSONObject("list").getJSONArray("resources"); //GETS RESOURCES ARRAY

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
    {
        String resource = arr.getJSONObject(i).toString();
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject(resource);

        String resourceObject = obj2.getJSONObject("resource").toString(); //RESOURCE OBJECT
        JSONObject obj3 = new JSONObject(resourceObject);


        String name = obj3.getJSONObject("fields").getString("name"); //REACHED THE FIELDS
        float price = (float)obj3.getJSONObject("fields").getDouble("price");

    System.out.println(name);  
    System.out.println(price);


    }
```

Download : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Comment: Please check my EDIT 2.

Answer (score 0):

He is already using gson.

If you want to continue using gson and know the structure before, you could create classes that stores the data.

```
class GoogleRequest{
    private GoogleList list;

    public GoogleList getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(GoogleList list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
// class for list
class GoogleList{
    private Meta meta;
    private List<Resources> resources;

    public List<Resources> getResources() {
        return resources;
    }

    public void setResources(List<Resources> resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    public Meta getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    public void setMeta(Meta meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }
}
// create other classes here like the Resources class
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); // from gson
JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream)request.getContent()));

GoogleRequest list = new Gson().fromJson(root,GoogleRequest.class);
```

The GoogleRequest should hold a List object and a Meta object. gson will introspect and set the properties. gson will set properties to null if they where not introspected. So you could use.

```
if( list.getResources() != null ){
  // list is here
}else{
  // do some other code and parse diffrent json
}
```

If you don't know if it is a array or object create different classes to handle it for you. Just parse the data with new Gson().fromJson();

Now remember that you need right properties for the job. Let's say you have this json in java

```
 String json = "{\"price\" : \"554.520020\"}";
```

Then price needs to be Double or double. If you use Double you could check

```
if( obj.getPrice() != null ){
  System.out.println( obj.getPrice().intValue() );
}
```

Note: **you will loose precision if you cast double to int**

Comment: Please check my EDIT 2.

Comment: Create a holder for the resource object.  And parse it as above. Want full code example just let me know.

Comment: I got it now, and it works, please check my EDIT 3 if is this is a smart solution or not.